# Search for a keyword in C# and output the line as a string

Tags: c#, .net

How would it be possible to search for a string e.g. #Test1 in a text file and then output the line below it as a string e.g.

Test.txt

```
#Test1
86/100

#Test2
99/100

#Test3
13/100
```

so if #Test2 was the search keyword "99/200" would be turned into a string

Comment: what have you tried? Have you a problem with loading/processing the file or with the *logic* for this? Both problems are rather trivial (File.OpenText / ReadLine and a simple flag to remember if the last line began with "#Text" will do the job)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the file *once*, store the results in a dictionary. Then lookup in the dictionary.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var lines = File.ReadLines("testScores.txt");
var e = lines.GetEnumerator();
while(e.MoveNext()) {
    if(e.Current.StartsWith("#Test")) {
        string test = e.Current;
        if(e.MoveNext()) {
            dictionary.Add(test, e.Current);
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("File not in expected format.");
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can just say

```
Console.WriteLine(dictionary["#Test1"]);
```

etc.

Also, long-term, I recommend moving to a database.

Answer (score 1):

Use readline and search for the string (ex. #Test1) and then use the next line as input.

Comment: I agree - you beat me on the keys +1

Answer (score 0):

If the exactly above is the file format. Then you can use this

```
1. read all lines till eof in an array.
2. now run a loop and check if the string[] is not empty.
   Hold the value in some other array or list. 
   now you have items one after one. so whenever you use loop and use [i][i+1], 
   it will give you the test number and score.
```

Hope this might help.

Answer (score -1):

How about RegularExpressions? [here's a good example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/csharplanguage/thread/2FABB42E-7179-4E37-A52B-B3DBC9708AE1)

Answer (score -1):

This should do it for you:

```
        int lineCounter = 0;
        StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(path);

        while (!strReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string fileLine = strReader.ReadLine();
            if (Regex.IsMatch(fileLine,pattern))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pattern + "found in line " +lineCounter.ToString());
            }
            lineCounter++;
        }
```